# Hole in the Wall Help

Tags: plaster, hole-repair, access-panel

We had a pipe burst in our house that required plumber to cut a rectangle hole in the wall of our dining room to access it. Leak is repaired and I want to fix the hole. The wall is plaster with something under it from what the plumber said, so I am not sure what best route to fix this is.

What is best route to fix / repair the wall while also putting an access panel in the middle instead of just fixing the hole?

Any info is appreciated. I can do the work, I just dont know what I need to get it done.   I have included a photo

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Kinda looks like drywall (gypsum board) to me...

Comment: An access door covering the opening will save the hard work of trying to match the paint.  Repairing the drywall would be easy also, same piece(if in one piece) or a new piece, some tape and mud.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  I dont know the steps to do it right.  Its definately plaster on top / outside of the wall.  I want to do an access door, but not sure of process of putting in some drywall and an access panel?  I dont have the piece that was cut out.

Comment: Looks like rock lath plaster: plaster on a gypsum base.  You can fix it the way you would fix drywall but it tends to be both thicker and less uniform in thickness because the plaster is hand-applied.  Do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6qr97XtWsM) to patch it but shim between the backing planks and the new drywall with [cardboard drywall shims](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Strait-Flex-45-in-Drywall-Shims-DS-45/202343444)  to get it flush.  Add [access panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/14-in-x-14-in-Access-Panel-with-Frame-APD14/204352607)

Comment: Thank you very much...I appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you need an access panel?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I needed to patch a hole, but leave access. I made a small cabinet out of melamine shelving and installed between studs as a small display case. In your case, you would need to patch the sheetrock around the hole (assuming you don't need the wider access, or use wider face trim. When I need access, I unscrew the case and pull it from the wall.
[image: display case]